# Look up value, on another Excel sheet

Tags: excel, matching, vlookup

I have a small list of names with no emails on sheet one, and on another sheet (sheet 2) I have the master list of names with their emails in the adjacent column.

I want to look up the email associated with the name from the master list (sheet 2), and place it on the first sheet.

Here is what the data looks like:

Sheet 1:

[image]

Sheet 2:

[image]

In the first sheet I tried to use VLOOKUP to match the name with the emails on the other sheet.

My equation was

> =VLOOKUP(A8,Sheet1!A1:B285, 1, FALSE)

This ... did not work. Any idea on where to go from here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is:

```
=VLOOKUP(A8,Sheet1!A1:B285, 1, FALSE)
```

If you take a look at [VLOOKUP description](https://support.office.com/en-AU/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1), you will find the following description of the first parameter:

> The value you want to lookup. The value you want to look up **must be in the first column of the range** of cells you specify in table-array.

So your formula tries to find `name` in `email` column.

One possible solution is to change the order of columns in the look up sheet and use:

```
=VLOOKUP(A8,Sheet2!A1:B285, 2, FALSE)
```

(make sure the sheet name is right, it is not clear what are the names of both sheets).

More universal solution is to use `INDEX`/`MATCH` combination:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$285,MATCH(A8,Sheet2!$B$1:$B$285,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put your equation like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(A8,Sheet2!A2:B285, 1, FALSE)
```

because in your equation you are making reference to the first sheet, I mean you want to find a value in the same table as you are searching.

I expect it will works. Let me know if it is wrong.

**EDIT:** When I put A2:B285 it's because I suppose that the table in your sheet2 it's the full table but instead of that you have to select all the table in sheet2.

Comment: No sorry, did not work. I'm still getting the N/A in the cell.

Comment: @Chef1075 Mmm.. I edit the answer. Maybe it's because the range of the table. In the second parameter enter all the full second table. Try this and let me know again.

Answer (score 0):

VLOOKUP requires that the first column on Sheet2 is sorted in alphabetical order. Your formula (pointing at Sheet2!A2:B285) will probably work then!